# Should I ever configure a host with a public IP address to accept traffic from a private IP address?

Tags: security, firewall, cisco, ip-address

I connect the 'net with a public static IP (my router's IP address for NAT) and a /29 subnet  (for machines behind the router).

On my router, I have:

```
#sh ip route | inc x.x
     x.x.0.0/16 is variably subnetted, 3 subnets, 2 masks
C       x.x.196.62/32 is directly connected, Dialer1
C       x.x.206.72/29 is directly connected, BVI2


#sh run int dial 1 | inc zone
 zone-member security out-zone
#sh run int bvi 2 | inc zone
 zone-member security in-zone
```

The zone-pair is fairly restrictive.  I would like to relax the restrictions for clients which first connect via a remote-access VPN:

```
#sh run int virtual-template 1
 zone-member security relaxed-zone
```

Now clients connecting via VPN must be assigned a private IP address. (I don't allocate public addresses to clients, right?):

```
# sh ip local pool

 Pool                     Begin           End             Free  In use   Blocked
 RANET100                 192.168.100.230 192.168.100.250   20       1       0
```

So now if I want to get a packet to x.y.206.73 from 192.168.100.230, that's fine - the router has the information it needs.  But it means that the host x.y.206.73 would have to permit traffic to its public-scoped IP address from a private address ... something it would normally be configured to ignore!

So this is a dirty hack, right?  What is the True Path (TM)?  Should I just multi-home the hosts with the public IP addresses so that they also have a private IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's entirely reasonable to have this setup. Consider it thus:

Your 'internal network' consists of multiple networks:

- a globally routable /29
- a locally routable /24 for VPN users

Your public host doesn't care that it gets a connection from an RFC1918 address unless you configure it that way. Just let it happen.

No need to configure another IP.

Comment: I like the language 'globally/locally routable' versus 'public/private' addresses - that helps to clarify matters.

Comment: This is a better answer IMHO. Let the edge router ensure that no packet with a non-globally routable address arrives from a global interface, but let a host with a globally-routable address exchange traffic with both local-only and global hosts.

Comment: I find it easiest to worry about global/private addresses at one point (well, ideally it's >1 point :) ) - the network edge. Keeps things simple.

Answer (score 2):

"But it means that the host x.y.206.73 would have to permit traffic to its public-scoped IP address from a private address"

No it wouldn't, it'd mean that a host would have two IP addresses, which happen to have different routing expectations to the Internet as a whole.

There's no reason not to place more than one IP address on an interface; it's entirely possible, and in fact, IPv6, it's pretty much universal.  Just make sure that your address selection rules for outgoing connections use the right address for the right task.

Comment: OK, that answers the question.  Giving the host both private and public IP addresses is the best solution, then?

Comment: There's not enough information available to be able to say it's the *best* solution, but I'm fairly confident in saying it's *a* solution.